# Div position (margin:auto)

Tags: css-position

so I'm customizing my tumblr and my pagination is out of place. I put the pagination divs inside the content div so that it should vertically align on the bottom center of the page. but the pagination divs (the older and newer buttons) keep appearing on the bottom left corner instead of bottom center. i tried centering the pagination div with margin:auto and it seems to be stuck on the bottom left for some reason.

html:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="page">    
<div class="pagination">
{block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}"> ←OLDER </a>{/block:NextPage}</div>
<div class="pagination">
{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}"> NEWER→ </a>{/block:PreviousPage}</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#content .pagination{margin:0 auto;
background-color:blue;
color:white;
border-radius:15px;
font-size:20px;
font-family:broadway;
}

#content .pagination a{margin:0 auto;
                   color:white;
                   opacity:.5;
                   }
#content .pagination a:hover {
                          color:white;
                          opacity:1.0;
            filter:alpha(opacity=100);
                         }
#content #page .pagination {
                        display:inline-block;
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set

```
#page {
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you are able to change the html markup, you could do your pagination like this:

```
<div class="pagination-wrapper">
    <div class="pagination">
        {block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}"> ←OLDER </a>{/block:NextPage}
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
        {block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}"> NEWER→ </a>{/block:PreviousPage}
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.pagination-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thank you! not only it worked, i also understand why i was doing it wrong. i tried to text-align:center .pagination div before instead of the #page div

Comment: how do i go about increasing the space between the OLDER button and the NEWER button? so that the OLDER BUTTON will be on the left side and the NEWER BUTTON will be on the right side? (but both buttons still vertically aligned and inside #content div)

Comment: Ah... that's a few new questions. Let me see if I can whip up a fiddle.

Comment: i'm having a difficulty. i tried making 2 separate blocks of divs for the newer button and older button, then putting a display:inline-block so that they will be horizontally aligned. but i think messed the whole thing up =)

Comment: I think you could put it pretty much anywhere.

Comment: thank you! would you kindly give me the proper tumblr coding? im still pretty rought with tumblrs coding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43938/discussion-between-jameslafferty-and-lo-mat)